# Angular MDC migrate schematics is not upgrading legacy material in components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am upgrading my Angular app, I have angular material legacy components which I want to upgrade to MDC components, but when I was using the schematics, It updates the scss only without doing anything in the components, What could be the issue? Am I missing something in angular.json?

[image]

[image]

***Update***
I figured the issue is with components not getting selected properly from terminal from my side, we have to use spacebar to select the component
[image]